# Rare effect when toggling BaseLayer in leaflet with react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

My application shows a map with `react-leaflet` and uses `LayersControl` to switch between an `OSM TileLayer` and `HERE TileLayer`. The code is as follows:

```
 <LayersControl position="topright">

      <LayersControl.BaseLayer
                    name={this.props.intl.formatMessage({id:'map.normal_map'})}
                    checked={true}
                >
                    { tileLayerOSM }
                </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
                <LayersControl.BaseLayer name={this.props.intl.formatMessage({id:'map.terrain_map'})}>
                  { tileLayerHERE }
                </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
</LayersControl>
```

The problema I see is the following: when moving the OSM map, some 'squares' are downloaded from `HERE` while they are not ready with `OSM`. See the network trace:

[image]

I would like to avoid this behavior, since it is a bit annoying for the user, who see changes in the visualization for a short period of time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience using Leaflet with React, but these is clearly not the desired behaviour.

In Leaflet that (retrive the both base layers at the same time) happens when you add both to the map. Something like:

```
const accessToken = 'foo';
let osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
const mapbox = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/basic-9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}';

const map = L.map('map').setView([42.2, -8.8], 12);

map.addLayer(osm);
map.addLayer(mapbox); // only one should be added to the map
```

or directly when instantiating the map:

```
let map = L.map('map', {
        center: [42.2, -8.8],
        zoom: 12,
        layers: [osm, mapbox] // only one should be added to the map
    });
```

With this kind of baselayers you only must add one to the map and use the layer control to switch between one or the other. When only one is added only the tiles for one of the maps are requested, saving bandwith.

As a "shot in the dark" I will try to make the checked value explicit for all layers. First both as a harcoded false, nothing should be shown in the map. Then one with `checked=true` harcoded and the other with false, and so on. Probably the trouble is how those attributes are managed.

Comment: Makes sense. However in the official docs (https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html#layerscontrol), they include two `BaseLayers` within `LayersControl`. I will play a bit with it and stop using `react-leaflet` to interact directly with `LeafLet` if can't get it work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. But in the example none of the layers has the `checked` attribute so if you copy&paste nothing should be shown.

Comment: I have just tried it out and keep working in the same way, but the radiobuttons to select the layer have disappeared. I will try to open a issue in the react-leaflet github.